# Make an <a> link or <button> automatically start dialing

Tags: javascript

I'm assuming there's got to be a way to get an `<a>` tag to automatically dial a phone number, because Google does it, but how?

Just using a `tel:` href opens a dialer, but it doesn't begin the phone call like when you click on the "Call" button (see below) from Google search results on mobile.

It looks like they're using JS to achieve this, but I'd love to know how so we can implement this into our call links on client websites. Clicking a button to call and also having to click the "dial/call" button in your dialer creates an extra barrier for conversions that I'd love to see eliminated. Any help is greatly appreciated!
[Looked up a local guitar shop that I clicked to call yesterday (which automatically started the phone call) and opened the inspector. The call link html is highlighted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19fgw.png)

Comment: You could check the "Event Listeners" to see what Javascript is attached by my understanding is that it just depends on how the phone handles `tel:` links.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is OS / Browser combination dependent.

The reason this works in your screenshot is the use of Google Chrome on a Google (Android) device. If you observe the same link using FireFox on android, or Safari on IOS you see different behaviors.

For more information reference the use of [Intents](https://developers.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

Comment: That's kinda what I figured, but I was hoping there might be a workaround. I appreciate the response!